# Why is there manpage for sync(1) and sync(8) and how do they differ?

Tags: man, coreutils

I see there are two different utilities in Linux manpages and I don't understand the difference.

There is sync(1) and sync(8), and they look eerily similar.

https://linux.die.net/man/8/sync

https://linux.die.net/man/1/sync

I am probably missing something obvious. How do they differ? (I know that sync(2) is a syscall. But sync(1) and sync(8) look basically the same?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first link shows an old copy of the `sync` man page which used to be provided by [the Linux man-pages project](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/); this [was removed in 2014](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/commit/?id=fcea836046ea4ffd7f9f4aac9c9cca82717fcb60) following [this discussion](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2014-03/msg00014.html) because GNU `sync` had its own manual page (formerly provided in the project called [Fileutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/fileutils/), which is what the first man page refers to). The former shipped in section 8, the latter in section 1.

Nowadays, GNU `sync` is part of [Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), and its man page is still shipped in section 1.

Both man pages on die.net are outdated; compare the section 1 version to [the current version](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sync.1.html). die.net hasn’t been updated in many years.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I get for clicking on the first link on google instead of actually doing `man` myself. :)

Comment: It’s somewhat unfortunate that die.net still dominates search results...

Answer (score -2):

As for the sections, according to "man man", section 1 is for "Executable programs or shell commands" whereas section 8 is for "System administration commands (usually only for root)".

That said, [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt) gives better info in regard to your question as to why sync is present in both sections.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. This is rather a comment than an actual answer. Which is why I voted for deletion. Cheers, and good luck next time.